# Mongoose: Get last subdocument of document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to find the last created subdocument in one of the documents and get it's data. I  have model Posts which contains main post and comments on it. Comments field contains subdocuments and one of the fields is date when the comment was created.

The other thing is that I need to display Posts by the date of creation of last subdocument.

Comment: This may not be the best schema for what you need to do.  For sorting I recommend adding last-comment date to main post document that you can index and sort by.  To get last sub document you will probably need to use aggregation framework, unless you make comments a separate collection rather than embedding.

Comment: But is the separate collection for comments good idea in MongoDB or it's better if they're in subcollection?

Comment: it's better they are in separate collection, otherwise your parent document will grow unbounded which is bad for performance and unnecessary - if you had 50K comments on a post and you were displaying the post, would you need to get back all 50K of comments when you fetched the post or would that just be slowing you down?  Embed just the first few comments for performant displays of the beginning of the conversation and put the rest in a separate collection.